# box-shadow being cut off by parent element

Tags: css

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

.strip {
  height: 120px;
  background-color: rgb(111, 0, 255);
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 48px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 179);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content min-content 1fr;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 217, 255);
}

.gallery {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(166, 255, 0);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  z-index: 100;
}

.list {
  background-color: rgb(214, 58, 131);
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="strip">strip</div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="gallery">gallery</div>
    <div class="list">
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

as you can see the gallery element have box-shadow but it cutting of from the parent div
if i will change .main css to be overflow:visible the box shadow will not cut off but it will disable the list element scroll

is there a way to combine those two together ? (scroll and box-shadow not cutting of)

btw : the strip element sometimes can be render and sometimes not

thanks

Comment: For future questions put your code inside here, not in external sources, especially if it is only html and css.

Comment: This is a tough one, as it's impossible to have `overflow: scroll` *and* keep your box-shadow. Some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32924860/show-box-shadow-of-child-element-while-parent-element-has-overflow-hidden) and [here](https://front-back.com/how-to-make-absolute-positioned-elements-overlap-their-overflow-hidden-parent/). Of course the obvious solution is to just add padding/margin that allows for the box shadow. But that might not be the look you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, remove the `overflow: hidden` from `.main` (And from all parents if there are any), and use `min-height: 0` to make the `flex: 1` take the remaining height (And not more).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

.strip {
  height: 120px;
  background-color: rgb(111, 0, 255);
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
  // overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 0; // <-- this will cause the flex: 1 take only the given height.
  margin: 48px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 179);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content min-content 1fr;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 217, 255);
}

.gallery {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgb(166, 255, 0);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  z-index: 100;
}

.list {
  background-color: rgb(214, 58, 131);
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="strip">strip</div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="gallery">gallery</div>
    <div class="list">
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item">
        <h1>Item</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```